# $(M\cap E)(M\cap F)= M$ for linearly disjoint fields $E$ and $F$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $E$ and $F$ be linearly disjoint fields over a base field $K$ (all contained in an algebraic closure $\overline K$). Suppose there is an extension $M/K$ contained in $EF$.
Is it true that $(M\cap E)(M\cap F)= M$?
I was not able to show it. Does anybode have an idea?

Comment: Is $EF$ minimal field containing $E \cup F$? If yes, then take $E = \mathbb{Q} (\sqrt 2)$, $F = \mathbb{Q} (\sqrt 3)$, $M = \mathbb{Q} (\sqrt 6)$. We have $M \cap E = M \cap F = \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: You are right, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not true, see mihaild's comment.